# How to use angular ngx-translate pipe in ngx-charts?

Tags: angular, angular-pipe, ngx-translate, angular-i18n

I want to add pipeline to my ngx-chart xAxisLabel and yAxisLabel.

```
<ngx-charts-bar-vertical
              [view]="view"
              [scheme]="colorScheme"
              [results]="single"
              [gradient]="gradient"
              [xAxis]="showXAxis"
              [yAxis]="showYAxis"
              [legend]="showLegend"
              [showXAxisLabel]="showXAxisLabel"
              [showYAxisLabel]="showYAxisLabel"
              [xAxisLabel]="xAxisLabel"
              [yAxisLabel]="yAxisLabel"
              (select)="onSelect($event)">
</ngx-charts-bar-vertical>
```

The code I changed below caused an error.

```
[showXAxisLabel] = {{ 'xAxisLabel' | translate }}
```

Error:

> Error in /turbo_modules/@angular/compiler@8.2.14/bundles/compiler.umd.js (2603:21)

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-simple-ngx-charts-pmreqo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

How could I achieve ngx-translate pipe with ngx-charts?

Comment: You're not using the correct binding syntax, could you try `[showXAxisLabel]="'xAxisLabel' | translate"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credited to @Amer's comment, the syntax for using `translate` pipe was wrong. Have to be:

```
[xAxisLabel]="'xAxisLabel' | translate"
```

OR

```
xAxisLabel="{{'xAxisLabel' | translate}}"
```

And according to [ngx-charts Vertical Bar Chart](https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-charts/examples/bar-charts/vertical-bar-chart#inputs),

| Property | Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| showXAxisLabel | boolean | show or hide the x axis label |
| showYAxisLabel | boolean | show or hide the y axis label |
| xAxisLabel | string | the x axis label text |
| yAxisLabel | string | the y axis label text |

You need to assign the **text with translate pipe to `[xAxisLabel]` and `[yAxisLabel]`**,

but **not `[showXAxisLabel]` and `[showYAxisLabel]`**.

```
<ngx-charts-bar-vertical 
  [xAxisLabel]="'xAxisLabel' | translate" 
  [yAxisLabel]="'yAxisLabel' | translate">
</ngx-charts-bar-vertical>
```

[Sample Solution on StackBliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-simple-ngx-charts-rflk1v?file=src/app/app.component.html)